# What is the difference between the applied, external force and the generalized force?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, terminology, definition

in analytical mechanics, we define the generalized force using the applied force times $dr/dq$. If I want to express the difference between the external and generalized force in words in order to distinguish between them, what should I say?

Comment: What is $r$? What is $q$?

Comment: Applied force has the unit N, generalized force not necessarily. External force is applied force

Answer (score 0):

If you have taken vector analysis you might know about the direction cosines represented by the derivatives.

Similarly here what dr/dq actually signifies is a kind of cosine,  a kind of dot product with a unit vector along the generalized coordinate.

It is like asking what is the component of the actual force along this particular generalized coordinate.

In reality it is just a mathematical expression but pops up deriving the lagrange equations but if you think about it signifies something that we all have been doing in newtonian mechanics and hence the name.

Lets take an example . Suppose a free particle is placed at the origin and a constant force of F is applied on it which makes an angle
θ with the x  axis .

In newtonian mechanics we take the COMPONENT of the force along x axis and y axis and simply apply newtons second law

F cosθ = dpᵢ/dt

F sinθ =dpⱼ/dt

where i and j are obviously the x and y axis

now if you do this with analytical mechanics you will get the same result

to understand better lets ask a question what is dr/dq?

even simper ,what is r ?

we know r= x î + y ĵ + z k̂

then the previous question dr/dq is obviously î

Now the generalized force is the dot product of the force with this derivative ,meaning dot product of force with the unit vector along x axis .What is this? Nothing but F cosθ

So in a gist ,generalized force is the force along your particular generalized co ordinate . It is truely like the name suggests a force that is general, that is , it doesnt bind you to your co ordinate axis ,it sets you free

NOTE : Generalized force in reality may represent torque, Applied force or really anything